# How can I use strings to describe test cases in Java?

Tags: java, testing, junit

With JUnit, the description of my test cases would normally in the method name, like:

```
@Test
public void should_return_6_if_distance_is_2km() {
}
```

or

```
@Test
public void shouldReturn6IfDistanceIs2km() {
}
```

Which is not quite readable.

But with the testing frameworks of other lanuage, like javascript, or scala, I can use:

```
describe("Taximeter") {
    it("should return 6 if the distance is 2km") {
        ...
    }
}
```

which is more readable with plain strings.

Is it possible to do this in Java?

Comment: The answer by @Michael shows how to make error messages more readable, but I don't think you can always describe test cases in a single sentence. For this reason, you should JavaDoc your test methods like you do with your production code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spectrum](https://github.com/greghaskins/spectrum) is quite close to my requirement:

```
@RunWith(Spectrum.class)
public class ExampleSpec {{

    describe("A spec", () -> {

        final int foo = 1;

        it("is just a code block with a run() method", new Block() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Throwable {
                assertEquals(1, foo);
            }
        });

        it("can also be a lambda function, which is a lot prettier", () -> {
            assertEquals(1, foo);
        });

        it("can use any assertion library you like", () -> {
            org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(1, foo);
            org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(true, is(true));
        });

        describe("nested inside a second describe", () -> {

            final int bar = 1;

            it("can reference both scopes as needed", () -> {
                assertThat(bar, is(equalTo(foo)));
            });

        });

        it("can have `it`s and `describe`s in any order", () -> {
            assertThat(foo, is(1));
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a good Assertion Framework, like [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/), [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html) or [Truth](https://github.com/google/truth) will automatically result in better error messages at least. And of course, the assertions themselves will be much more readable than just using `assertTrue`, `assertEquals`, etc.

For example, AssertJ:

```
assertThat( myVar ).describedAs( "myVar" ).isEqualTo( 6 );
```

This will result in an error message (if myVar != 6) that includes the name "myVar", the expected value and the real value.

Comment: I would like to add [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) framework and [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) library (Hamcrest matchers) to this list cause they have very readable assertions syntax too. Examples: `verify(someDao, atLeastOnce()).getMyEntity()` and `assertThat(resultDto, sameBeanAs(expectedDto).ignoring("id"))`

Comment: Strictly speaking, Mockito is not an Assertion-, but a Mocking-Framework, so it cannot be used to test states, just verify calls to mocks and spies.

Answer (score 3):

The assert methods in JUnit allow you to do something similar.  You could do something like:

```
assertTrue("Should return 6 if the distance is 2km but returned " + myvar, myvar == 6);
```

This allows your code to be readable but only returns a message if the expected condition isn't met.

Comment: You got the order of parameters wrong: the message is first.

Comment: meh, that is what I get for not actually typing it in the IDE and just writing it on the fly...  fixed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Scala-Part, is this just a Description or runnable Testcode?

If Description:
For readable but automateable  Testcase-Descriptions check out
cucumber (https://cucumber.io) or jBehave (http://jbehave.org)

If runnable Code:
To try to make the code of the Testcase itself more readable hamcrest (https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial) could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own [Runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) for this and use it with [@RunWith](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering the same thing for a long time. The closest I have found to the "describe"-"it" way of organizing tests is the NestedRunner. [Check it out here](https://github.com/NitorCreations/CoreComponents/blob/master/junit-runners/README.md)

It is not the same and has some limitations, but definitely an improvement.

Just saw the link OP posted - [Spectrum](https://github.com/greghaskins/spectrum) is even better! I am definitely trying it out asap. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests written with [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) framework are pretty readable. The docs promise the ability to “write beautiful tests” that are “more readable” and “produce clean verification errors.” See for yourself:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.eq;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepositoryMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserService userService = new UserService();

    @Test
    public void testLoadUserByUsername() {
        // Expected objects
        User demoUser = new User("user", "demo", "ROLE_USER");

        // Mockito expectations
        when(userRepositoryMock.findByUsername("user")).thenReturn(demoUser);

        // Execute the method being tested
        User userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername("user");

        // Validation
        assertThat(userDetails.getUsername(), eq("user"));
        verify(userRepositoryMock).findByUsername("user");
    }
}
```

To have Mockito available with Maven the following dependency should be used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.47</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And to have Mockito available with Gradle the following dependency should be used:

```
dependencies { testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+" }
```